# assignment of variables from possibly undefined fields

Tags: javascript

this is my question:
what is the best (most clear) way to deal with this situation?

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
var result = (data[0][0] && data[0][0][0]) ? data[0][0][0] : null;
```

What I am trying to do is assigning to result the content of data[0][0][0] but sometimes that data might not be available and if I just say:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
var result = data[0][0][0];
```

I could receive an error because data[0][0] is not initialised.
My solution works but I am sure that there is a better way to do it...maybe using exceptions?
Thanks

Comment: If `data[0][0][0]` contains a false value, your check would fail.

Comment: True! I was sure that I was missing some cases...thanks! Any proposal?

Comment: Check for undefined which will make it longer. ;)

Comment: Well....at this point I will leave it like that. I will never have a false value in data[0][0][0] anyway..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a strong believer in writing clear code; consider the following rewrite:

```
var result = null;
if (data[0][0] && typeof data[0][0][0] != 'undefined') {
  result = data[0][0][0]; 
}
```

This is easy to understand and arguably more correct than your original code. If `data[0][0][0]` is always an object or `null` you could of course write this instead:

```
var result = null;
if (data[0][0] && data[0][0][0]) {
  result = data[0][0][0]; 
}
```

There's no real shortcuts; you have to check `data[0][0]` first before you can check `data[0][0][0]`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I see your point. Do you say 'more correct' because you are actually checking the type instead of the content?

Comment: @user2283224 Yes, it doesn't rely on what JavaScript considers truthy.